# How to apply condition to indices of numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 2D NumPy array, and I want to set values to the array provided that its index satisfies a particular condition.

I can do this using the `for` loop by:

```
import numpy as np

new_a = np.ones((5,10), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(new_a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(new_a.shape[1]):
        if (np.nan_to_num(i/np.nan_to_num(j))) >= new_a.shape[0]/new_a.shape[1]:               #(This is the condition, which I may change a little as needed)
            new_a[i, j] = 0
            
print(new_a)

''' Output:                                                                                    (This gives a upper triangular matrix)
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
'''
```

> **But the problem is that I want to do this for large 2D arrays of dimension about `(10000, 20000)`.** So `for` loop will be very slow.
> How can I do this efficiently (in less time), using NumPy or any other
> library?

Note: I don't want solutions to create a diagonal matrix (as I want to apply the code for many different conditions). I am looking for solutions to '**efficiently applying conditions to indices of numpy array**' (a much faster approach rather than using `for` loops).

Comment: No, it works good only for rectangular arrays. Also, I want to change the condition according to the different problems. It will be helpful if you tell the approach on 'How to apply condition to indices of numpy array efficiently?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the array indices like this:

```
import numpy as np

new_a = np.ones((5,10), dtype=np.float32)
indices = np.indices(new_a.shape)
y_indices = indices[0]
x_indices = indices[1]
```

To get the indices where you particular comparison holds true, you can then:

```
locations = np.nan_to_num(indices[0] / indices[1]) >= new_a.shape[0] / new_a.shape[1]
```

To apply this, simply:

```
new_a[locations] = 0
print(new_a)
```

Returning

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can gain speed (paying in additional memory consumption) by using `np.meshgrid` to vectorize the operations:

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(new_a.shape[1]), np.arange(new_a.shape[0]))
idx = np.nan_to_num(yv/xv) >= new_a.shape[0]/new_a.shape[1]
new_a[idx] = 0
print(new_a)
```

prints

```
>>> new_a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This gives error : boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1. on new_a[idx]=0 line

Comment: when I tried for :  new_a = np.ones((1000,2000), dtype=np.float32)

Comment: Yes, I had accidentally deleted a `np.arange()` when removing the hardcoded values. It's fixed now